# uniformly convergent subsequence of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am working a problem in which we start with a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and a sequence $\left\{a_n\right\} \subset \mathcal{H}$ with $||a_n|| = 1$.  We also assume that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left< x, a_n \right> = 0 \text{ for all } x \in \mathcal{H}. $$  Note that if we define $T_n \colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathbf{C}$ by $$T_n(x) = \left< x, a_n \right>, $$ then $T_n$ is a bounded linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$ and $||T_n|| = ||a_n|| = 1$.  Then $\left\{T_n\right\}$ is equicontinuous and converges pointwise to $0$.

A particular estimate I want to make seems like it's going to either live or die depending on whether it is true that there exists a subsequence $T_{n_k}$ which converges uniformly to $0$, which is my question.

I am really close to satisfying the hypotheses of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem, except for the (crucial) compact hypothesis (note $\left\{a \in \mathcal{H} \colon ||a|| = 1\right\}$ is compact iff $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional).  I was hoping that this might be mitigated by the fact that I am dealing with linear operators on a Hilbert space...  But I really have no idea whether my desired result is true or not, so I'm asking you experts out there if it is.

-Thanks.

---

Edit:  As Robert points out below, the result is false as stated.  What I'm really interested in is whether the following statement is true:

> For fixed $\epsilon > 0$, there exists large $N$ such that $$ |\left< a_i, a_j \right>| < \epsilon \;\;\;\;\; (i, j > N, i \neq j).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For separable $H$, fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_j\}\subset H$ and let 
$$
a_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\,\sum_{k=n}^{2n}e_k,
$$
For any $x\in H$ with $\|x\|\leq1$ we have 
\begin{align}
|\langle x,a_n\rangle|&= \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\,\left|\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\langle x,e_k\rangle\right|\leq\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\,\left(\sum_{k=n}^{2n}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}(n+1)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=\left(\sum_{k=n}^{2n}|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.
\end{align}
On the other hand, 
\begin{align}
\langle a_n,a_{n+1}\rangle&=\frac1{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}\,\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\sum_{j=n+1}^{2(n+1)}\langle e_k,e_j\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}\,\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}1\\ \ \\
&=\frac{n}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}\geq\frac12\ \ \ \  \text{ for } n \geq2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct in saying that if $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional, then the hypotheses are absurd? (Because it would be forced that $||a_n|| \to 0$.)

Comment: Yes, in finite dimension weak and strong convergence agree.

Comment: The edit was little too careful, when the inequality holds for all $n\geq2$.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, and sorry about the edit.

Comment: No worries :) I didn't care enough to check whether it really held for all $n$ or not.

Answer (score 3):

$T_n(a_n) = 1$, so there is no subsequence that converges uniformly to $0$ on any set that contains all $a_n$.

EDIT: The answer to your second question is also no.  There is nothing in the hypotheses that forbids $a_{2n+1} = a_{2n}$, for example.

Comment: Hi Robert, I should have foreseen that special case.  However, what I'm really after avoids this case: I want to show for fixed $\epsilon$ and large $n$, $$\left< a_i, a_j \right> < \epsilon \;\;\;\;\; (i, j > n, i \neq j). $$

Comment: As a curiosity, it would seem that in the case $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional both your argument and the Arzela-Ascoli theorem should hold, contradicting each other.  However, in this case, the assumptions of the problem are absurd, and so the result is vacuously true.

Comment: Regarding your edit: True indeed... I suppose I could get around it with another edit, but Martin's answer suggests this would be futile.